# softDelete use three Model Pivot

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php8

Структура SQL

*user*

*news*

*tags*

***pivot***

user_id

news_id

tags_id

**deleted_at**

Создал модель для сводно таблици.
так же для belongToMAny использую used(Pivot Table);

когда я пытаюсь удалить из сводной таблици через detach($id). Мягкое удаление работает.
А как восстановить?
Удалить полностью?
Кто сталкивался?
Без кулибинских технологий,а чисто ларой, бо накулибничал я уже у себя и сам)